# Given an unsorted integer array, find the first missing positive integer

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

Here is the problem, any advice about code improvement, more efficient implementation in terms of time complexity, functional bugs, etc. are appreciated.

> Given an unsorted integer array, find the first missing positive
>   integer.
>
> For example,
>   Given `[1,2,0]` return `3`,
>   and `[3,4,-1,1]` return `2`.
>
> Your algorithm should run in O(n) time and use constant space.

```
def firstMissingPositive(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    if not nums:
        return 1
    for i,v in enumerate(nums):
        if v > len(nums):
            nums[i]=-1
        elif v <= 0:
            nums[i]=-1
        else:
            while i+1 != nums[i] and 0<nums[i]<=len(nums):
                #print i, nums[i]-1, nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1]
                v = nums[i]
                nums[i] = nums[v-1]
                nums[v-1] = v
                #nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i]
            if nums[i] > len(nums) or nums[i] <=0:
                nums[i] = -1
    for i,v in enumerate(nums):
        if nums[i] != i+1:
            return i+1
    return len(nums)+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print firstMissingPositive([1,2,0])
    print firstMissingPositive([3,4,-1,1])
```

Comment: So, if I understand the second exemple correctly, 0 is *not* a positive integer?

Comment: And what about the other constraints? Can there be duplicated numbers in the array? What should `[4, 5, 7, 8]` return, 6 or 1?

Comment: @LinMa a full description of this challenge would really help. Could you please add a link / full description to your question ?

Comment: Not sure about O(n), for + while can give you O(n**2)

Comment: As it is implemented now, it's O(n^2) because you cycle through all number and in the worst case again through `n-1` number, which means `n(n-1)` time complexity. You can use count sorting to get a linear time, but that would be O(n) extra space. I don't think you can do it in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: @ChatterOne not really, in a worst case you will have in total N number of swaps, so it's not for each element you can have up to N, it's in total you will get N swaps in the worst case since you swap elements until they get their position or just ignore them. For example one of your worst cases is when your list elements are shifted to 1 index, e.g [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] this is a worst case where you will have in total 6 swaps.

Comment: @Alex I see your point. I think you're considering only the swaps, but maybe you should consider (also) the comparisons. In the worst case you'll still do one swap, but `n` comparisons for each `n-1` in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PEP8**

Python uses underscore as naming separator in function and variable names, see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

**Naming**

```
for i,v in enumerate(nums)
```

It's better to use some obvious names so instead of `i,v` you should use `index, value`

**Improvements**

You've got a right idea on how to solve this, but there are some minor things in your implementation that can be improved.

```
for i,v in enumerate(nums):
    if v > len(nums):
        nums[i]=-1
    elif v <= 0:
        nums[i]=-1
    else:
```

this part can be simplified to

```
if  0 >= value > len(nums):
    continue
```

Now your while loop can make infinite number of cycles on such list `[3,4,3,-1]` so you need to handle this, also you don't have to replace items that are `<= 0` or items that are `>= len(nums)` with `-1` you can just skip them.

So in the end your code should look like this:

```
def first_missing_positive(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    if not nums:
        return 1
    for index, value in enumerate(nums):
        if len(nums) < value <= 0:
            continue
        while index + 1 != nums[index] and 0 < nums[index] <= len(nums):
            v = nums[index]
            nums[index], nums[v-1] = nums[v-1], nums[index]
            nums[v-1] = v

            # Don't create infinite loops
            if nums[index] == nums[v-1]:
                break

    for index, value in enumerate(nums, 1):
        if value != index:
            return index
    return len(nums) + 1
```

Comment: Love your comments, Alex. mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution:

```
def first_missing_positive(nums):
    cnt = {}
    for x in nums:
        cnt[x] = 1

    fnd = 1
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if cnt.get(fnd, 0) == 0:
            return fnd
        fnd += 1
    return fnd
```

According to `timeit` on my local machine it is a bit faster than the solution from Alex. Is it breaking the "O(n) time and use constant space" requirement?

Comment: It is not using constant space.

Comment: Since the space used directly depends on the data processed due to the `dict`?

Comment: Yes. Go through this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844411/1190388 :)

Comment: Hei @RandomDude!
Sorry but totally unrelated...
I own a t-shirt with the face shown in your avatar...
Who is this guy? :)