# Find the first missing positive integer in an array of integers

Tags: java, beginner, programming-challenge, complexity

The problem is the one explained in [Given an unsorted integer array, find the first missing positive integer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149270/given-an-unsorted-integer-array-find-the-first-missing-positive-integer)

> Given an unsorted integer array, find the first missing positive
>   integer.
>
> For example,
>   Given `[1,2,0]` return `3`,
>   and `[3,4,-1,1]` return `2`.
>
> Your algorithm should run in \$O(n)\$ time and use constant space.

I am trying to learn Java 8+ and wrote the following code. Request any improvisations possible.

```
int firstPositive(int[] inputArray) {

    //Convert all negative numbers to 0.
    IntStream.range(0, inputArray.length).forEach(idx -> {
        if (inputArray[idx] < 0) inputArray[idx] = 0;
    });

    IntStream.range(0, inputArray.length).forEach(idx -> {
        if (Math.abs(inputArray[idx]) == 0) {
            inputArray[0] = -Math.abs(inputArray[0]);
        }
        else if (Math.abs(inputArray[idx]) - 1 < inputArray.length && inputArray[Math.abs(inputArray[idx]) - 1] > 0) {
            inputArray[Math.abs(inputArray[idx]) - 1] *= -1;
        }
    });

    OptionalInt res = IntStream.range(0, inputArray.length).filter(idx -> inputArray[idx] >= 0).findFirst();

    if (res.isPresent()) {
        return res.getAsInt()+1;
    }

    return inputArray.length+1;
}
```

Comment: Links can rot or become broken. [I included a description of the challenge in your question.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1994)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
if (res.isPresent()) {
    return res.getAsInt()+1;
}

return inputArray.length+1;
```

you could make use of the `orElse` method of `OptionalInt`:

```
return res.orElse(inputArray.length) + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Performance and readability are often a trade off. This \$O( n \log n)\$ solution just misses the \$O(n)\$ target, because we must sort the pre-filtered array, but it’s much easier to reason about a map/reduce in my opinion.

```
Integer[] nums = {1,2,0};
//Integer[] nums = {3,4,-1,1};
//Integer[] nums = {1,2,4};
//Integer[] nums = {1};
//Integer[] nums = {0};

 Integer result = 
    Arrays.stream(nums)
        .filter(x -> x > 0)
        .sorted()
        .reduce(1, (prev, curr) -> (prev == curr) ? curr + 1 : prev );

System.out.println(result);
```

I generally find it a bit strange that you’re using streams to generate what is essentially a loop (`forEach`) instead of turning the array into a stream and leveraging the power streams give you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier solution which is strictly \$\Theta(n)\$. Given \$\ell\$ the input list:

- Filter for just positive numbers: \$\ell_{>0} = \{i \in \ell\mid i > 0\}\$
- Compute the maximum and the sum of the elements of \$\ell_{>0}\$. Namely, \$m = \max \ell_{>0}\$ and \$ s = \sum _ {i \in \ell_{>0}} i\$
- Now there are two cases: whether it is missing a number in \$[1, m)\$ or it is missing \$m+1\$.
- We know that \$1 + 2 + \dots + m=m\times(1+m)/2\$. Call this sum \$t\$. Compare \$t\$ with \$s\$. If they are equal,  it means that the sum is complete, so return the next integer, \$m+1\$. Otherwise, the difference will tell you which number is missing: \$t-s\$.

You can achieve constant space by storing just three numbers: \$m\$, \$s\$ and \$t\$. Where \$m\$ and \$s\$ will require \$|\ell|\$ steps to be computed. Consider this pseudocode.

```py
m = 0 # You can safely assume 0 here (or l[0] if you wish)
s = 0
for i in l:
   if i > 0:
     s += i
     if i > m:
       m = i

t = m*(m+1) /2
```

Of course, then computing \$t\$ is \$\Theta(1)\$.

Comment: Clever solution, but it only works when exactly 0 or 1 positive integer is missing from the array. For example, it would fail with `[1,2,4,5,7]`. Also you stated that the computing time is `O(1)`, but it is `O(n)` where `n` is the input array length.